# Unique Values in list

Tags: r

I have a vector with names such as

```
names <- c('John Smith','Emily Jones', 'John Marcus', 'Emily Stan', 'Tom Rhodes')
```

and I do

```
strsplit(names,' ')
```

which returns me a list of lists of the names. How can I get a list or vector of the unique first names which are John, Emily, Tom? I need to do x[[1]] to access a specific list so I'm not sure how to use unique in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could split the names on spaces using `strsplit` and then from each element of list get the first element and keep only the `unique` ones.

```
unique(sapply(strsplit(names, '\\s+'), "[[", 1))
#[1] "John"  "Emily" "Tom"
```

---

Another option using `word` function from `stringr` package, where we can extract specific words from the string.

```
library(stringr)
unique(word(names))
#[1] "John"  "Emily" "Tom"
```

Answer (score 1):

With `sub`:

```
unique(sub("\\s\\w+", "", names))
# [1] "John"  "Emily" "Tom"
```